# PHP. Forward request to another server as is

Tags: php, curl, proxy, request, forward

Server A is sending messages to Server B. I need to insert Server C with PHP script between them.

So I want it to work like this:

Server A -> Server C (do some stuff with data and forward request further) -> Server B.

I need Server B to recieve exactly the same request, that was sent from server A.  I don't need Server C acting as proxy, just send request as is, and that's all

How could I do it?

I've tried something like this, but in did not work:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'Server B URL');  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Server B returned 200, but did nothing. I don't have access to it, so I don't know what blocked the request.

Comment: this is not a job for curl, this is a job for socket_*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

making sure curl exactly replicates any request to the smallest detail? that's not really a job for curl, but for socket_*. i bet some would say that this is not really a job for PHP either, but PHP surely is capable of doing it, in a single-threaded manner. use the socket api to accept connections from server A, read the request, do your processing, forward the request to server B as it was received, read the response from server B, and send that response back to server A.

example (could call this ServerC.php):

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);
if(php_sapi_name() !== 'cli'){die('this script must run in cli mode.');}
$port = 9999;
$targetIP = gethostbyname ( 'example.org' );
$targetPort = 80;
assert ( false !== filter_var ( $targetIP, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP ) );
var_dump ( $targetIP, $targetPort );

y ( ($listen = socket_create ( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP )) );
register_shutdown_function ( function () use (&$listen) {
    socket_close ( $listen );
} );
y ( socket_bind ( $listen, '0.0.0.0', $port ) );
y ( socket_listen ( $listen ) );
y ( socket_set_block ( $listen ) );
echo 'listening for connections... ', PHP_EOL;
while ( false !== ($newconn = socket_accept ( $listen )) ) {
    echo 'new connection from ';
    socket_getpeername ( $newconn, $peername, $peerport );
    echo $peername . ':' . $peerport . PHP_EOL;
    y ( socket_set_block ( $newconn ) );
    $data = '';
    echo 'reading request... ';
    $data = socket_read_all ( $newconn, 2 );
    var_dump ( $data );
    echo 'done.' . PHP_EOL;
    // client didnt send any bytes in a while, assume we got the whole request...
    {
        // do whatever processing you need to do between requests in here.
    }
    {
        // now to forward the request.
        y ( ($targetSock = socket_create ( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP )) );
        y ( socket_set_block ( $targetSock ) );
        y ( socket_connect ( $targetSock, $targetIP, $targetPort ) );
        echo 'connected to target. forwarding request... ';
        socket_write_all ( $targetSock, $data );
        echo 'done.', PHP_EOL;
        unset ( $data, $newdata );
        $data = '';
        echo 'reading response... ';
        $data = socket_read_all ( $targetSock, 2 );
        var_dump ( $data );
        echo 'done.', PHP_EOL;
        socket_close ( $targetSock );
    }
    echo 'sending response back to client... ';
    socket_write_all ( $newconn, $data );
    echo 'done.', PHP_EOL;
    socket_close ( $newconn );
}
function y($in) {
    if (! $in) {
        $str = hhb_return_var_dump ( socket_last_error (), socket_strerror ( socket_last_error () ) );
        throw new \Exception ( $str );
    }
    return $in;
}
function n($in) {
    if (! ! $in) {
        throw new \Exception ();
    }
    return $in;
}
function hhb_return_var_dump(): string // works like var_dump, but returns a string instead of printing it.
{
    $args = func_get_args ();
    ob_start ();
    call_user_func_array ( 'var_dump', $args );
    return ob_get_clean ();
}
function socket_write_all($sock, string $data) {
    $len = strlen ( $data );
    while ( $len > 0 ) {
        $written = socket_write ( $sock, $data );
        if ($written === false) {
            throw new RuntimeException ( 'socket_write failed. errno: ' . socket_last_error ( $sock ) . '. error: ' . socket_strerror ( socket_last_error ( $sock ) ) );
        }
        $len -= $written;
        $data = substr ( $data, $written );
    }
    return; // all data written
}
function socket_read_all($sock, int $sleep_sec = 2): string {
    $ret = '';
    while ( true ) {
        sleep ( $sleep_sec ); // ...
        $buf = '';
        $read = socket_recv ( $sock, $buf, 9999, MSG_DONTWAIT );
        if ($read === false || $read < 1) {
            return $ret;
        }
        $ret .= $buf;
    }
}
```

(this script is slow, processes only 1 request at a time (concurrent requests are buffered by the OS for socket_accept, though), and synchronous. but it could be optimized and made fully async with socket_select & co, if its worth optimizing)

Comment: What about if the request is sent to a unique URL and not only for the domain (example.org/test)?

Comment: @justaguy this approach is url-agnostic, the server doesn't care what the domain/url is, it just forwards it all.. however, it will all be forwarded to the same url as was requested by the source... if you request proxy.com/blabla , the forwarded request will also go to /blabla

Comment: GREAT THANKS!!!
I will make it a little harder now... :)
What if I want to server A to send all requests to server C (example.com/forwarder.php), but to add a unique param to allow me (as server C) to send his requests to different 3rd party servers (like example.com/forwarder.php?server=test will send requests to test.com/api.php)

Answer (score -2):

Try changing this line

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);
```

to:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($_POST));
```

When you make a regular cURL request, you cannot use an array (`$_POST` is an array) directly as a value for `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`. You have to transform that array into a postdata string, which is exactly what `http_build_query()` does. It converts for example

```
["name" => "my first name", "email" => "my@email.com"]
```

into:

```
name=my%20first%20name&email=my@email.com
```

Comment: that would not forward GET data, cookie data, nor http headers (such as user agent), nor would it guarantee that the post data was encoded equally, nor even that the same encoding was used (for instance, you can't determine from $_POST whether `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` was used, PHP abstracts and decodes it for you. your http_build_query approach would always result in using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, regardless of what encoding server A used.)

Comment: also, when server A actually encoded with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, you won't be able to tell/replicate if Server A encoded the data per RFC1738, RFC3986, or some other scheme (because PHP decodes them both equally)

Comment: also, at least `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` supports redefining the same variable several times, like `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

foo=9&foo=8` (idk why people actually would ever want to do that, but i have seen it in the wild, and it is supported by both Firefox and Chrome)

- here, PHP will just put $_POST['foo']  to the last provided value of foo, and discard any previous definitions. meaning that when you http_build_query it, the previous definitions of foo (that is overwritten in the same request) won't be forwarded to ServerB